# How the image is saved in the Draftwysiwyg in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I use the `Draft wysiwyg`  for  my React project .

But I can only get simple text, but I can not get and save the image.

How can I save both text and image on my server using `Draft wysiwyg`?

component text editor:

```
class TextEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      uploadedImages: [],
    };

    this._uploadImageCallBack = this._uploadImageCallBack.bind(this);
  }



  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });

  
  };

  _uploadImageCallBack(file) {
   
    let uploadedImages = this.state.uploadedImages;

    const imageObject = {
      file: file,
      localSrc: URL.createObjectURL(file),
    };

    uploadedImages.push(imageObject);

    this.setState({ uploadedImages: uploadedImages });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve({ data: { link: imageObject.localSrc } });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
   
    return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
     
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          toolbarClassName='toolbarClassName'
          wrapperClassName='wrapperClassName'
          editorClassName='editorClassName'
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
          toolbar={{
            inline: { inDropdown: true },
            list: { inDropdown: true },
            textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
            link: { inDropdown: true },
            history: { inDropdown: true },
            image: { uploadCallback: this._uploadImageCallBack },
            inputAccept:
              "application/pdf,text/plain,application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-excel",
          }}
        />
       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TextEditor;
```

I use the `TextEditor` component, which is a class component, in another component, which is the functional component, and from there I send the data to the server.

thank for those to help me!